# ElasticSearch path.home exception on Mac OSX El Capitan using basic Java app

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to get myself familiar with Elastic Search for one project, but I can't seem to get rid of an exception. This is the basic code:

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.fieldstats.FieldStats;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.*;
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.*;
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.*;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
        Client client = node.client();

        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                                .startObject()
                                .field("user", "kimchy")
                                .field("postDate", new FieldStats.Date())
                                .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                                .endObject()
                )
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
    }
}
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: path.home is not configured
    at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:128)
```

I have googled quite a lot, but nowhere can I find an answer as to where to set this parameter "path.home". I have tried setting it in the elasticsearch.yml file both insider the project ../resources folder and inside the install folder of elasticsearch, but didn't succeed.

Maybe I am a bit blind, but your help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this myself. It turned out, that I was using the BETA version 2.0 of ElasticSearch which had this problem. I have switched to version 1.7.2 and everything is fine now.